# Is every finite weak group a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

**Definition:** Let $W$ be a set and $\circ:W\times W\rightarrow W$ be a function. We say that $(W,\circ)$ is a a weak group iff there exists unique $e\in W$ such that $\forall x\in W[x\circ e=e\circ x=x]$ and for every $x\in W$ there exists a unique element $x^{-1}$ in $W$ such that $x\circ x^{-1}=x^{-1}\circ x=e$. Finally, for every $x,y\in W$, we have: 
$$x\circ(x^{-1}\circ y)=y\,\,\,\,,(y\circ x^{-1})\circ x=y$$

**Question:** Is there a finite weak group that is not a group ?

I tried trying playing with Cayley tables for some time to find a finite weak group that is not a group but didn't find any.

Thank you

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yes. This can be inferred from the fact that $\circ$ is a function from $W\times W$ to $W$

Comment: Are you claiming $x\circ(x^{-1}\circ y)=y\,\,\,\,,(y\circ x^{-1})\circ x=y$ as part of the axioms?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Yes they are part of the axioms of weak groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example for an infinite weak group which is not a group is the algebra of **octonions** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).

Analogous to the finite quaternion group $Q_8$, the set containing the positive and negative generators of the octonions is a finite weak group but not a group.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Every weak group is a group. We already have an identity and inverses, so we need to show that $\circ$ is associative. For all $a,b,c\in W$, we have $b^{-1}\circ (b\circ c)=c$ so that
$$(a\circ b)\circ c= (a\circ b) \circ b^{-1} \circ (b\circ c) = a \circ (b\circ c).$$</strike>

Edit: I just realized an error. It should be 
$$(a\circ b)\circ c= (a\circ b) \circ (b^{-1} \circ (b\circ c) )...$$
This does not seem to work anymore.